# How do I insert a page into zend navigation container

Tags: zend-framework, zend-navigation

I am currently using Zend_Navigation to create a menu from an XML file, so far so good the menu renders correctly.  My problem is that I need to add page(s) to a specific location within the navigation container.  So far I have:

```
$this->_navContainerConfig = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH .
            '/configs/navigation.xml', 'nav');

        $this->_navContainer = new Zend_Navigation($this->_navContainerConfig);

        $this->_navContainer->findById('defaultindex')->addPage(array(
            'label'         => 'Open Prints',
            'module'        => 'default',
            'controller'    => 'artwork',
            'action'        => 'list',
            'params'        => array(
                'medtyp'        => 2),
            'resource'      => 'default:artwork',
            'privilege'     => 'list',
            'route'         => 'default'
        ));
```

This just adds a subpage to the page id 'defaultindex', I need the page to be added after the 'defaultindex' page.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Many thanks in advance and a Merry Christmas to all,

Garry

Answer (score 0):

You can use method addPage directly from Zend_Navigation_Container

```
$this->_navContainer->addPage(your_array);
```

It will add your page after all pages already in container. If you need custom order you need to extend Zend_Navigation_Container and add methods to rewrite property $_index of pages in container to sort them in order you want

Comment: Thanks for you answer.  The solution I adopted in the end was to place all the pages in my XML file and removing the ones I didn't need afterwards.

$page = $this->_navContainer->findOneBy('id', $mediumType['medium_type_id']);
$this->_navContainer->removePage($page);